# Manual logged screen_view events sometimes have screen_name - (not set)

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, firebase-analytics

My project consist of obj-c and swift classes. I use Firebase 7.3.0.

I manually log screen_view event for my screens. I call this method in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear like this:

```
@objc class MyAnalyticConstants: NSObject { 
    static let myScreenName = "AwesomeScreen"
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        MyAnalyticsClass().logScreenViewEvent(name: MyAnalyticConstants.myScreenName)
    } 
}

class MyAnalyticsClass {
    func logScreenViewEvent(name: String, parameters: [String: Any]? = nil) {
        var param = [String: Any]()

        if let parameters = parameters {
            param = parameters
        }

        param[AnalyticsParameterScreenName] = name
        logEvent(name: AnalyticsEventScreenView, parameters: param)
    }

    func logEvent(name: String, parameters: [String: Any]?) {
        analytics.logEvent(name, parameters: parameters)
    } 
}
```

I turned off automatic screenview reporting by setting FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled to NO (Boolean) in the Info.plist. I use struct with static names for my screens.

However, sometimes I see (not set) value for "screen_view" event inside my google analytics path exploration for production. I can't catch this while using DebugView.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZPdm.png)

I would really appreciate it, if somebody could help me to fix or explain it.

**EDIT:**
I swizzled firebase method

```
 + (void)xxx_logEventWithName:(NSString *)name
          parameters:(nullable NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)parameters {
[self xxx_logEventWithName:name parameters:parameters];
if ([name isEqualToString:@"screen_view"] && [parameters[@"screen_name"] length] <= 3) {
    NSLog(@"%@", @[][1]);
}
```

and jumped through app during 30 min. I didn't catch up crash. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there are a few things you could typically do in this case.

0. I wrote it as an afterthought, but it's something you should make sure of before doing technical debugging that follows: you should go to your analytics property/view and debug the filters. Maybe you have replacing filters interfering with your values, but I presume you checked your data in a full and unfiltered view where your app is the sole "stream" of data. This is important. The bug can come from a different app to this property, so either make sure you're the only source, or make sure you filter out other sources/apps/platforms.
1. Check your logEvent function calls where you either send `AnalyticsEventScreenView` or just the `"screen_view"` string as the first parameter. You see how the Firebase lib uses one function to send all kinds of events? They now treat screenviews as events. Which has its elegancy, but also may lead to unintended mistakes. Check what the globals actually mean in here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-cpp-sdk/blob/0c8c8b29bc2d62d66c6ac49ff2c3fb04f815a687/analytics/ios_headers/FIREventNames.h
2. Check your `logScreenViewEvent` function calls. Pay attention to cases when you pass the first parameter as a variable. Also make sure you're never setting the AnalyticsParameterScreenName, which is also known as a string `"screen_name"` from here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-cpp-sdk/blob/0c8c8b29bc2d62d66c6ac49ff2c3fb04f815a687/analytics/ios_headers/FIRParameterNames.h in the parameters dictionary, the second attribute. Cuz setting it there will effectively overwrite whatever is the first attribute you're setting. I actually usually suggest having only one argument for the screenview function declaration, especially to avoid collisions like this.
3. Oh, almost forgot. Make sure you ALWAYS use your neat `MyAnalyticsClass` wrapper and never call the native logEvent(). I would just check all files where you include the Firebase sdk and see if it should be replaces with the wrapper.
4. Finally, if the above didn't help, you can insert the check in both your function wrappers to throw an error whenever the event name equals to `"screen_view"` and the `"screen_name"` parameter's length not more than 2 character (I'm just trying to include all falsy values, so null, undefined, nil, whatever). And run unit tests or even better - regression testing with things set like that. Well, or manually test it out, watching for the errors in the console rather than the web debugger.

Comment: Thank you for reply.
0. Yes, I use inly one source.
1. I have only 1 place with AnalyticsEventScreenView constant and don't use screen_view at all.
2. The same answer like in 1.
3. I checked it. Everything fine.
4.  I'll try it. If I find something, I'll write here.

Comment: I didn't find anything.